# Limit ansible playbook by `hosts` of plays

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory file like:

```
[my_domain]
255.255.255.255

[production:children]
my_domain


[load_balancer:children]
my_domain

[webservers:children]
my_domain
```

I have a `playbook.yml` like:

```
---

- hosts: webservers
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Hello webservers

- hosts: load_balancer
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Hello load_balancer
```

When running the following command it runs both the plays in the playbook, i.e. it prints "Hello webservers" and "Hello load_balancer":

```
ansible-playbook ./playbook.yml --limit "webservers:&production"
```

I can get it to only run the webservers play by adding a tag to it and using `tags` on the command line such as:

```
...
- hosts: webservers
  tags: ['webservers']
  # or if using roles then:
  # roles:
  #   - { role: provision_webserver, tags: [ 'provision_webservers' ] }
  ...
```

And use:

```
ansible-playbook ./playbook.yml --limit "webservers:&production" --tags "webservers"
```

I was hoping the `limit` arg would work not only on the inventory file but also on the `hosts` value of each play.  [The docs seem to suggest this is possible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html) though they give the example using `ansible` and a one off command rather than `ansible-playbook` and a playbook:

> This can mean what hosts to communicate with, but in terms of Playbooks it actually means what hosts to apply a particular configuration or IT process to.

I think the answer is that I am using playbooks wrong and [should only have one play per playbook](https://gist.github.com/marktheunissen/2979474#file-pedantically_commented_playbook-yml-L33-L37) which necessarily means it will only have one `hosts` and [you select which plays you want to run by changing the `playbook<-abc>.yml` you are using](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#top-level-playbooks-are-separated-by-role).  However that last link also suggests you can just use `--limit` to set which hosts.  Very confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right, as per [best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#top-level-playbooks-are-separated-by-role) you may want to split different types of configurations to separate playbooks to be able to run them separately.

But this piece of text may be a bit confusing:

> This is analogous to the “–limit” parameter to ansible but a little more explicit:
>
> ```
> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit webservers
> ansible-playbook webservers.yml
> ```

**It is true only if hosts in `webservers` group are not part of any other group.** Otherwise (as in your example) if host `server1` is in groups `webservers` and `load_balancers`, then plays for webservers and load balancers will be applied for this host.

Also, as you correctly noted, you can mark some parts of your playbooks with tags and use `--tags` to limit playbook runs by this criteria.

Sometime I use a trick to have the same host under different inventory names so Ansible treat them as different hosts:

```
[webservers]
myhost_ws ansible_host=myhost

[load_balancers]
myhost_lb ansible_host=myhost
```

This way `myhost_ws` and `myhost_lb` is actually the same server, but `--limit webservers` will execute only first play from this playbook:

```
- hosts: webservers
  ....

- hosts: load_balancers
  ....
```

But keep in mind that with this setup any fact gathered for `myhost_ws` during the first play are not available for `myhost_lb` during the second play directly (but you can still fetch them via `hostvars['myhost_ws']`).

Comment: "It is true only if hosts in webservers group are not part of any other group."  I suspected as much :)  Neat trick with `ansible_host=...`.  For the moment I'll stick with the current multi play playbook and tags.  Thank you for the rapid answer.